# Why don't eclipse run configurations survive a merge?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, merge

I had some nice eclipse run configurations I had created while working on a branch in SVN.  I then merged these changes back into the trunk, and now my eclipse run configurations are gone.  Why?  My eclipse configuration directory is totally separate from my svn directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving your run configurations as "shared". They will be saved as .launch files that you could add to your SVN repository to make sure they don't get lost again.

Example [here](http://carbidehelp.nokia.com/help/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_run_com.htm)

Comment: No, the main thing I'm suggesting is to keep the run configurations separate from your eclipse workspace. Then you can use them from multiple workspaces, check them into SVN (if you want), etc. I don't know what happened when you did the merge, but maybe this will help.